# Magic item ID: scarab that stops bleeding and teleports dying PC to safe place

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, equipment, teleportation

I'm trying to find an item that I saw, I'm pretty sure it was a scarab but not 100% on that. The effect of the item was that it would stop bleeding if the PC was at 0 or lower hp and at -10 hp it would teleport the PC's body to its "sanctuary" or home and preserve it for 18 days after which, if it is not fixed, it will die.

I'm pretty sure it is a Pathfinder/3.5 item but it may not be.

Comment: It sounds like a variant of the Scarab of Stabilization - which appeared in DMGII for D&D 3.5 - but that doesn't include the 'teleport body' effect.  I offer that bit for anyone who might know what an artifact-level version of that Scarab is called.

Comment: And adding on to my comment on the answer, this is probably the scarab I read in conjecture with the armor mentioned in the answer. Thank you as well sgfit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Death's Preservation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/death-s-preservation-banded-mail) is an armor with the same contingent teleport and preservation effect you asked for. Though it doesn't prevent you from dying, it just extends the time-limit on resurrection so that you can benefit from e.g. Revivify or Breath of Life instead of higher level spells.

Comment: That description looks spot on enough that it is probably the item. I was reading quite a few descriptions earlier. Thank you!